# Configure apps to store data on external SD?

Tags: cyanogenmod, settings, external-sd, camera, storage

I have a S5 with Cyanogenmod v12.  I've gone through every setting screen I could find but was unable to locate where to tell the default Camera app to store pics/vids on SD instead of internal memory.   I realize I could move them over, but that's an added step and inconvenience.

Is there a way to configure the default Camera app to save to SD?  If not, is there a camera app that comes with this ability?

Answer (score 0):

In cynogenmod's camera app there are no further settings it must have .I think you should try this app- google camera .

Answer (score 0):

You can root your phone and then you can use Picture 2 SD app in that way your requirement can be fulfilled.

Check this XDA Developer Source :

http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-pictures2sd-v1-0-6-makes-camera-t2408880